# Postdoc vs. academic position

Tags: postdocs, faculty-application, academic-life

I'm a citizen of a third world country, currently living in Canada. I've completed a 2-year postdoc position here and recently got an offer for an academic position at one of the reputable universities in my home country. They want me to initially obtain a research funding, though, which will take at least a year to get.

On the other hand, I was offered a second postdoc fellowship at one of the top universities in Canada.

I'd like to follow a career pathway where I can be an academic member eventually. However, if I accept the faculty position, I know that I'll never be able to have much funding throughout my career. On the other hand, if I accept the postdoc position and work hard, I might be able to apply to few Canadian universities for a faculty position, tough I don't know what my chances are, as it will be more competitive.

I just wanted to hear your opinion on which path to take.

Comment: It really depends on your life goals. Any answers would be highly based on opinions and personal preferences.

Comment: Always and always faculty possitions

Comment: The title of the question looks strange to me; a postdoc is an academic position.